# Porteus. Saving changes

Tags: linux, portability

I've faced a problem with configuration of Porteus (portable OS, linux based, http://www.porteus.org/).

There are 2 problems:

1) it loads through different boot menu (where are only 2 options: boot with default settings and shutdown, I can configure the first one via F2 which opens submenu). I have a different menu when I boot from VirtualBox.

2) I cannot save anything (e.g. home folder). I'm trying to place save file on the same flash-drive with Porteus. I've modified /boot/syslinux/porteus.cfg (

APPEND initrd=initrd.xz changes=/mnt/sdb/savefiles/porteussave.dat

in

[LABEL LXQt; MENU LABEL Graphics mode (LXQt)]) but I cannot see this option in a boot menu.

If you have any good tutorial about Porteus and its configuration I'll be glad to have a link from you.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about OS's are best-suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh.. Okay. I'm sorry. I'll post it there then